# Linking GTM server container with GCP（AppEngine）

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-tag-manager, server-side

We are a sales partner of GCP.

We are aware that when using GTM's server container
In order to use GTM server containers, you need to provision (connect and link) with GCP's AppEngine.

If we, as a reseller, install GCP for our customers, can we do the setup?
Is it possible for us to configure the settings?
Since the GCP configuration itself will be done in the customer's environment, will the customer be responsible for the configuration?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you will have to in one way or another do the setup of GCP for server-side tracking. Otherwise you're not derlivering an MVP product, which is definitely a reasonable expectation from the client.

It's odd that this question is asked here. It's not a technical question, but rather a business ethics question. There's no value in reselling GCP if you're not providing some level of setup and support.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
I just wanted to know if it is technically and authoritatively possible for a reseller partner to do the provisioning.
In conclusion, I understood that it is technically possible, and whether the reseller partner does it or not is a matter of business ethics.